# I'm trying to delete a linked list.But it is running into an finite code

Tags: c, singly-linked-list

```
 void delete_list()
    {
     tr=header; //tr is`also defined at the top near struct node.
    while(tr!=NULL)
     {
     q=tr; // q is defined at the top as a pointer.
     tr=tr->next;
     free(q);
     }
     return;
    }
```

when I call this function in the main method it doesn't give the desired output.

Comment: This code is OK, the problem is in code that you didn't show. To get better help, post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I wouldn't say that this code is OK. We don't know the type of 'tr' and initialisation of 'header', and how elements of the type should be freed.

Answer (score 0):

You should also set the pointer 'header' to NULL afterwards.
And maybe all your other freed pointers.

Also make sure that during creation, the 'next' pointer is explicitly set to NULL or a valid pointer.

Comment: Im printing it in the display function. But still its not showing!

Comment: void display()
{
tr=header;
while(tr!=NULL)
 {
    printf("%d\n",tr->data);
     tr=tr->next;
}

Comment: void palindrome()
{
    int count=0;
    int i;
    tr=header;
while(tr!=NULL)
 {
    tr=tr->next;
    count++;
}
char arr[count];
tr=header;
while(tr!=NULL)
 {
     for(i=0;i<count;i++)
 {
   arr[i]=tr->data;
   tr=tr->next;
 }
    //tr=tr->next;
 }
tr=header;
while(tr!=NULL)
 {
     for(i=count-1;i>=0;i--)
     {

         if(arr[i]==tr->data)
         tr=tr->next;
         else
        {
         printf("not a palindrome");
         return;
        }
     }
       printf("is a palindrome");
}

}

Comment: im trying to check whether the above code is a palindrome. it is accepting the data, but not printing whether it is a aplindrome or not

Comment: Your display function does not really look strange, but still, to know if it is called, start it with a printf("Debug: start display\n");

You could also keep track of a counter and debug each step.

Also is the tr->data type really an int?